# Trouble with algebraic manipulation: proving and factorisation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I have been trying to proof the following for more than a day, but to no avail. I have tried several ways, partial/full expansion/factorisation etc but I just cannot prove it. I would love indirect nudges and hints, rather than direct answers since I wish to work it out myself, as I'm sure many do prefer of the questioner.

I am supposed to prove, starting from LHS that

$\frac{1}{4}(m)(m+1)(m^2+m+2)+(m+1)[(m+1)^2+1]=\frac{1}{4}(m+1)(m+2)(m^2+3m+4)$

I zoomed in on the the fact that $\frac{1}{4}$ and $(m+1)$ can be factorised i.e.

$LHS = \frac{1}{4}(m)(m+1)(m^2+m+2)+(m+1)[(m+1)^2+1]$

= $\frac{1}{4}(m+1)[m(m^2+m+2)+4(m^2+2m+2)]$

Seeing that $(m+2)$ was also factorised on the RHS (what I'm working towards), I sought to also factorise $(m+2)$ out. I mistakenly thought I saw an opportunity to do this:

= $\frac{1}{4}(m+1)[m(m^2+m+2)+2(2)(m^2+2m+2)]$

= $\frac{1}{4}(m+1)[m(m^2+m+2)+2(2m^2+4m+4)]$

And now, unfortunately, I am unable to factorise because $(m^2+m+2)\not= (2m^2+4m+4)$. In any case, none of them are equal to the expression $(m^2+3m+4)$ that I'm trying to obtain (see RHS).

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious yet crucial here, some technique of manipulation or something. Would really appreciate any hints or nudges in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The left-hand side Can be written as
$$(m+1)\left(\frac{1}{4}m(m^2+m+2)+(m+1)^2+1\right)$$
and this is equal to
$$(m+1)\left(\frac{m(m^2+m+2)+4(m+1)^2+4}{4}\right)$$
and this is equal to
$$\frac{(m+1)(m+2)(m^2+3m+4)}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Focus on the expression that you have in brackets after your first (correct!) step:
$$\left[m(m^2+m+2)+4(m^2+2m+2)\right].$$
And now, don't overcomplicate the problem! Just go ahead and multiply it out and simplify completely. Then either see how you can group some terms in order to factor out $(m+2)$; or use either long division or synthetic division of polynomial to divide that polynomial by $(m+2)$.

Comment: However, I'm still puzzled - if $(m+2)$ could be factorised out this way after full expansion...why didn't my initial method allow me to obtain the expression $m^2+3m+4$?

Comment: It was this that led me to believe there was no use fully expanding anyways...

Comment: @Charlz97: What method?? Randomly observing an $m$ in one place and a $2$ in another? Not seeing something doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. You didn't see a common factor, but that doesn't mean that there's no common factor -- in fact, that doesn't mean anything at all. Maybe there's no common factor indeed, but maybe we need to group the terms in a different way. A random attempt at arranging the terms is **NOT** a method.